# cpu_quota's does not validate from chef-client

Tags: chef-infra

I wrote a cookbook with chef_client_systemd_timer. I added `cpu_qoute` the resource's propertie, but the propertie doesn't validate from the chef-client while its is working. I have added my cookbook and chef-client's error messages on below.

Best Regasds.

```
# chef-client -v
Chef Infra Client: 18.0.185

# cat cheftimer.rb
#
# Cookbook:: general
# Recipe:: cheftimer
#
# Copyright:: 2023, The Authors, All Rights Reserved.

chef_client_systemd_timer 'Run Chef Infra Client' do
  cpu_quota '150'
  interval '10m'
  splay    '1s'
end
```

```
[2023-04-20T06:34:59+03:00] FATAL: Chef::Exceptions::ValidationFailed: chef_client_systemd_timer[Run Chef Infra Client every 1 minute] (general::cheftimer line 7) had an error: Chef::Exceptions::ValidationFailed: systemd_unit[chef-client.service] (general::cheftimer line 107) had an error: Chef::Exceptions::ValidationFailed: file[/etc/systemd/system/chef-client.service] (general::cheftimer line 261) had an error: Chef::Exceptions::ValidationFailed: Proposed content for /etc/systemd/system/chef-client.service failed verification :systemd_unit (Chef::Resource::File::Verification::SystemdUnit)
```

Comment: Hi, I watched 
`https://www.linkedin.com/video/event/urn:li:ugcPost:7061476357385433088/`. Thanks for you related my question, but problem is going on. I installed chef-client and workstation with rpm. This recipe is working normally without `cpu_quota '150'` option. Also other recipes are working. I tried `chef-client -zo recipe[general::cheftimer]` but its doesn't solve.